# Simplify if condition to check of optional field attribute is present

Tags: java, optional-parameters

What is a simpler way to write the following:

```
Builder requestBuilder = new Builder();
if(myPlan.getSomeField().isPresent()){
     requestBuilder.setSomeFieldId(Optional.of(
                    NullableField.ofNullable(myPlan.getSomeField().get().getId())));
}
```

I tried to use `orElse` but it doesn't seem to match my requirements.

Comment: Do you mean something like `requestBuilder.setSomeFieldId(myPlan.getSomeField().map(SomeFieldType::getId).orElse(null))`? Or does `setSomeFieldId()` take an `Optional` parameter in which case the `orElse(null)` wouldn't be necessary? Or yet better: `myPlan.getSomeField().map(SomeFieldType::getId).ifPresent(id -> requestBuilder.setSomeFieldId(id))`

Comment: BTW solution from @Thomas comment can be simplified even more: `id -> requestBuilder.setSomeFieldId(id)` can be replaced by `requestBuilder::setSomeFieldId`